# NextJS Google Drive API using Service Account getting Insufficient Permission

Tags: next.js, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I'm writing a simple NextJS app to list files in a Google Drive folder.

- the G Drive folder is owned by my personal account, and shared with a Service Account created in GCP
- the `creds.json` contains the correct key added on the Service Account

The code is simple, and has been seen in many other tutorials ([1](https://www.labnol.org/google-api-service-account-220404), [2](https://youtu.be/xHflVKsY9PM)):

```
const credsDir = path.join(process.cwd(), '.');
const credsFile = fs.readFileSync(credsDir + '/creds.json', 'utf-8');
const credsJson = JSON.parse(credsFile);

const authClient = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  credsJson,
  scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
});

const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: authClient });

const response = await drive.files.list()
// Also tried drive.files.list({ driveId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx })
// Also tried other operations besides listing files
```

The error received is:

```
error - GaxiosError: Insufficient Permission
    at Gaxios._request [...] {
  response: {
    config: {
      url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files',
      method: 'GET',
      userAgentDirectives: [Array],
      paramsSerializer: [Function (anonymous)],
      headers: [Object],
      params: {},
      validateStatus: [Function (anonymous)],
      retry: true,
      responseType: 'json',
      retryConfig: [Object]
    },
    data: { error: [Object] },
    headers: {
      'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000',
      'cache-control': 'private',
      connection: 'close',
      'content-encoding': 'gzip',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      date: 'Fri, 07 Apr 2023 09:40:28 GMT',
      server: 'ESF',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      'www-authenticate': 'Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error="insufficient_scope", scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appfolder https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.resource https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly.metadata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"',
      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
      'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
      'x-xss-protection': '0'
    },
    status: 403,
    statusText: 'Forbidden',
    request: { responseURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files' }
  },
  config: {
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files',
    method: 'GET',
    userAgentDirectives: [ [Object] ],
    paramsSerializer: [Function (anonymous)],
    headers: {
      'x-goog-api-client': 'gdcl/6.0.4 gl-node/17.9.0 auth/8.7.0',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
      'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/6.0.4 (gzip)',
      Authorization: '<some bearer token>',
      Accept: 'application/json'
    },
    params: {},
    validateStatus: [Function (anonymous)],
    retry: true,
    responseType: 'json',
    retryConfig: {
      currentRetryAttempt: 0,
      retry: 3,
      httpMethodsToRetry: [Array],
      noResponseRetries: 2,
      statusCodesToRetry: [Array]
    }
  },
  code: 403,
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'Insufficient Permission',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'insufficientPermissions'
    }
  ],
  page: '/api/gdrive-images'
}
```

There are some solutions out there around this but are very old and don't seem to match my particular case.

What silly configuration could I possibly be missing?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your current issue, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your current issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your current issue, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
const credsDir = path.join(process.cwd(), '.');
const credsFile = fs.readFileSync(credsDir + '/creds.json', 'utf-8');
const credsJson = JSON.parse(credsFile);

const authClient = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  credsJson,
  scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
});

const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: authClient });

const response = await drive.files.list()
```

#### To:

```
const credsDir = path.join(process.cwd(), '.');
const authClient = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: credsDir + '/creds.json',
  scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
});
const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: authClient });
const response = await drive.files.list()
```

- When I tested this modified script, no error occurs, and I confirmed that `response.data` includes the file list of the drive of the service account.

#### Reference:

- [Using the keyFile property of Google APIs Node.js Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#using-the-keyfile-property)

Comment: I knew it's something silly. :) Credentials file wasn't loaded correctly. Your modification solved it.